# Nano World Wrap Without Hard Breaks

Tags: linux, text-editors, nano

How would I use the nano edtior to show the wrapping of the text, but without having the text broken by end of line characters? If I turn wrap off I'm only able to view one line of text, but if I have it on I get an /n character where the text is wrapped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the following to your `$HOME/.nanorc`:

```
## Enable soft line wrapping (AKA full line display).
set softwrap
```

Comment: Also add `set nowrap` to disable the destructive hard-wrapping of text